# How to refresh JSON cache?

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I am using Haneke for caching remote JSON. Caching works well but when I change the remote JSON file and call fetch (multiple times) still get old data from cache. Is any way how to force the fetch to update the cache?

Thank you!

i add

Hanekeswift files in my project

then
import Haneke

```
    _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.0001, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    func sayHello()
{
    data = dataJsonFromURL("http://www.arabfono.com/show22.php")
    myTable.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell22

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()

    let mindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    cell.titleNews!.text = mindata["title_topic"] as? String
    cell.timeNews!.text = mindata["created_date"] as? String
    cell.LabelNews!.text = mindata["view_topic"] as? String




    if let urlImg = NSURL(string: (mindata["img_topic"] as? String)!)
    {
        cell.imgNews.hnk_setImageFromURL(urlImg, placeholder: nil, format: nil, failure: nil, success: nil)
    }
func dataJsonFromURL(url:String)->NSArray
{
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!) {
        return ((try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as! NSArray)
    }
    else{
        return data
    }

}
```

Comment: Do attempt to clear the cache first before running another call? Show your code.

Comment: how i can clear the cashe ?

Comment: Add your code to the question on how you are fetching the data as starting point.

Comment: check it i added the code

Comment: Ok I looked at [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) project and I look at you code I do not see the cache happening. Also have you put in breakpoints at `myTable.reloadData() `and at `let mindata`? And see what happens when refresh the data?

Comment: how i do breakpoints in myTable.reloadData()